# Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name PublicSubnetAz does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a cloud formation template but I get the error

```
   Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name PublicSubnetAz does not exist
```

when i run the stack creation.

My template includes in the parameter section the following property:

```
  "PublicSubnetAz":{  
     "Type":"AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name",
     "Default":""
  }
```

and in my Conditions section I have

```
  "xxx":{  
      "Fn::Not":[  
         {  
            "Fn::Equals":[  
               {  
                  "Ref":"PublicSubnetAz"
               },
               ""
             ]
          }
       ]
   }
```

If I didn't set the PublicSubnetAz property while creating the stack i get the error reported. 
This is an expected behaviour as if the user don't select an AZ i get the first one when I need an AZ reference.

Do somebody has already addressed a similar problem and can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't have an optional parameter if this is an AWS-Specific Parameter.
There is a [feature request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=88652) dated 2012 but still not implemented